# python3 http.server response is not valid (Postman and other tools)

Tags: python, python-3.x, postman, artillery

I'm setting up a test server with the basic python3 library http and using the server module.

Testing my server, I've managed to properly get and see the response using curl in the terminal:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "http://localhost:8080/health"                 
{"health": "ok"}HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.7.3
Date: Sun, 12 May 2019 19:52:21 GMT
Content-type: application/json
```

But if I try to make the request with tools like Postman. With this one, I get the `Could not get any response` error message (the request does get to the server and it is processed, I can see that in the logging the server does).

Is there a specific way I have to format my response that I'm not seeing at the moment? This is how I do it:

```
    def _prepare_response(self):
        self._response_body({'health': 'ok'})
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','application/json')
        self.end_headers()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the curl output, it makes no sense: the "body" happens before the status line is even sent.

You're supposed to send the response body *after* the headers, not before. That means you must first send the response line, then send the headers, then end the headers, and only then write to `wfile` with the body content. So the code should look something like that:

```py
 def _prepare_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','application/json')
        self.end_headers()
        # move what I guess is a helper to after the headers
        self._response_body({'health': 'ok'})
```

And you probably want to make sure you're properly json-serializing the dict rather than just pass it off to str and hope it's JSON-compatible (I don't know what _response_body does).

Comment: I was about to respond myself with this exactly. Can you please edit your answer to include the proper order of the code?

Comment: Sure, I've added a version of _prepare_response which I think should improve things.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your Postman configuration. Otherwise itd quite hard to determine what is wrong.

However: If you cURL Call is working well, please import the whole command over Copy&Paste into Postman over Import-->Raw Text and try out if this request is working.

Comment: I did that copy paste you mention but the error persists. I dont know what configuration of Postman you are refering to